# android - how to loop through all activities?

Tags: android, colors, themes, spinner

In my android app, i can change the theme, but to see the change I have to exit the app and open it again.

This is how I change the theme.

```
ThemeSetterActivity.setStyle(signup.this);
```

which happens on the create event.

But is there some code like this (below) that I can run, and will change the theme for all the activities.

```
foreach (activity act in app) {
    ThemeSetterActivity.setStyle(act.context);
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can't do it that way.

What I do is have each activity keep track of what theme it is currently using.
Then in each activities on resume just check if the current theme is still what it should be, if not restart the activity.

An easy way to get that application wide is to just have your base activity class implement that behavior, and then have all activities extend that.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a theme to an Activity or application

To set a theme for all the activities of your application, open the AndroidManifest.xml file and edit the  tag to include the android:theme attribute with the style name. For example:

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

If you want a theme applied to just one Activity in your application, then add the android:theme attribute to the  tag instead.

Just as Android provides other built-in resources, there are many pre-defined themes that you can use, to avoid writing them yourself. For example, you can use the Dialog theme and make your Activity appear like a dialog box:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Comment: All true but that is not what he is asking. He is asking specifically how to dynamically change the theme, not how to set it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

use static field and store your theme id;
and in onCreate method use :

```
yourActivityObj.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
```

maybe id work;